# How to find which rspec test is taking so long

Tags: rspec

One (or a couple) of our tests are taking forever and we'd like to optimize them.

We have say 1000 tests so it's impractical for me to go through run each file.

Is there an easy to way to find the slow ones?

This is rspec 1.3

Answer (score 205, accepted):

In RSpec 2 and 3, you can use the `--profile` flag or add `--profile` to your `.rspec` file. This will track the top 10 slowest examples.

For RSpec 1, you can use `--format o` with `spec` command. It shows a text-based progress bar with profiling of 10 slowest examples. For more details [see this](http://rspec.info/documentation/tools/spec.html).

```
rspec --profile -- path/to/file/spec.rb
```

Comment: For me --profile option does not work with RSpec2. Any clues?

Comment: @YuriOmelchuk --profile may have been depricated. Use -p as instead of --profile. Just run rspec spec -p to list 10 slowest examples. Hope it helps

Comment: Does this exist for Cucumber as well?